# Issue on autodeploy to remote Tomcat with IntelliJ 2017.2

Tags: java, tomcat, artifact, autodeploy, intellij-idea2017

I needed to change my project from Php to Java/Spring.
Everything was perfect for changing right now (all new Releases: Spring5, Java9, Tomcat9 and some other cool new stuff).

Its been a while since i was developing with Java and Tomcat and I am very new to IntelliJ.

So now i have a Spring Project, many Libaries and a Tomcat running on a Server.
I know, i could just develope local, but thats no Option due to Project circumstances. I need to "live update".

Everything is setted up (JMX Port on Server, Debugport and so on).
If i manually trigger Artifactbuildung, the artifact (war exploded) looks good.
If i manually upload that artifact to the server and restart Tomcat, everything works perfectly. But this way it takes me several minutes with upload and deploying, this is very annoying.

But if i run the debug mode in IntelliJ and HotSwap classes (i even tried "Redeploy), IntelliJ gives me an Error "**Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.**".

```
10-Oct-2017 21:07:18.704 INFORMATION [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [<contextName>] has started
10-Oct-2017 21:07:22.638 INFORMATION [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [<contextName>] is completed
10-Oct-2017 21:07:32.645 WARNUNG [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess Exception processing loader [WebappLoader[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[<contextName>]]] background process
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.modified(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:674)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.modified(WebappLoader.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5461)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1366)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.openJarFile(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:94)
    ... 14 more

10-Oct-2017 21:07:42.648 INFORMATION [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload Reloading context [/<contextName>]
10-Oct-2017 21:07:42.648 INFORMATION [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/<contextName>] has started
10-Oct-2017 21:07:46.223 INFORMATION [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/<contextName>] is completed
10-Oct-2017 21:07:46.227 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(125)-79.208.253.91] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method createStandardContext
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

10-Oct-2017 21:07:46.350 INFORMATION [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [<contextName>] has started
10-Oct-2017 21:07:50.125 INFORMATION [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [<contextName>] is completed
```

Again: if i upload the same "content"/artifact to the server and manually restart, everything is fine, so i'm quite sure, its something about IntelliJ Config or remote settings in Tomcat.

Here are the Configs:

Server Tomcat Config from Logs:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 38001
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.110 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M26
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.112 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 2 2017 20:29:05 UTC
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.112 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.0.0
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.112 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.112 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.13.0-042stab124.2
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.112 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.112 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.112 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.113 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.113 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.113 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.113 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.113 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.113 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.113 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dnet.sf.ehcache.skipUpdateCheck=true
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.113 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.113 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.116 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseParNewGC
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.117 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.117 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.117 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.117 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.117 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.117 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.117 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.117 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=38001,suspend=n,server=y
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.117 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.117 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
10-Oct-2017 21:15:58.117 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
```

In Case its needed:
[Screeshots of IntelliJ Configs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3E_F6lVj1WaWGdfaXRaZUhqVVU)

So my Question: 
Why am i getting ZipExceptions when I HotSwap or Redeploy over IntelliJ 2017.2.4?
If i can provide anything else helpful, please let me know.

(also tried IntelliJ 2017.1.5)
(I tried it hundred times, so this is no upload/broken-library issue)

Comment: Hard to know, there is no root cause to the zip file failure. What is clear is that this is not the result of hot swapping, as the point of hot swapping is to not have to redeploy / restart the application which clearly is happening here. So it is in all situations redeployment that fails, for an unspecified reason.

Comment: So far, no solution or other hints. I'm out of ideas. Has anybody else an idea, where to start?
(i just tried to deploy on local machine, this is working).
Could it have something to do with the TomcatServer settings?